# QAbstractItemModel for QMetaObject, do I have to write it myself?

Tags: c++, qt, reflection, qobject, model-view

A suite of data models built on top of Qt's reflection system seems like a natural synergy, but I haven't found such a beast in the Qt library itself or from a 3rd party. Does anyone know if such a thing exists?

I'm look for data models for editing and displaying a collection of QObjects QMetaObject properties. I can kind of understand why this isn't included in the Qt library (as it would not be possible to expose all of QMetaObject in a clean way) but I'm hoping I don't have to write a bunch of data models and proxy models to display the hierarchies and properties of QObjects.

Comment: that sounds like a dynamic property grid, right? like in qt designer where it separates properties per each subclassed type of QWidget?

Comment: That would be one use for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are representing a tree of `QObjects` then [QStandardItemModel](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qstandarditemmodel.html) will probably suit your needs. If not, you would probably subclass that instead of `QAbstractItemModel`.

Comment: Finally got a chance to read the docs and experiment and it does seem to be good enough!